# Error on backup utility in Magento2 admin

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, backup

When I try to do a back up in admin using the utility it gives me the following error

```
Failed to save backup with error: Utility gzip not found
```

I have confirmed the gzip is loaded on the server (And I tested it)

Magento EE 2.0.7

[image]

Per Steve's instructions I did the following

```
php bin/magento support:utility:check -u
Utilities list:
gzip => /bin/gzip
lsof => /usr/sbin/lsof
mysqldump => /usr/bin/mysqldump
nice => /bin/nice
php => /usr/bin/php
tar => /bin/tar
sed => /bin/sed
bash => /bin/bash
mysql => /usr/bin/mysql
```

Comment: See if [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-spt-util.html#config-cli-spt-utils-trouble) helps you figure out why gzip appears to be missing.

Comment: Steve, I did run the backup command via the CLI and it worked. I also ran the utility you suggested and posted the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Magento root directory run:

`php bin/magento support:utility:paths`

This will generate `var/support/Paths.php` file and solve this error.

Comment: This works on 2.1.7.

Comment: Works for 2.3.4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The backup should happen even without Paths.php.
Try:

```
apt install gzip
apt install lsof
```

You can try to generate the backup via command line:

```
php bin/magento support:backup:code --name mycodebackup -o /var/www/magento2/var/log/
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, if your environment does not have a working 'which' command, then this error is generated.

We encountered this on a docker container.

Running:

```
yum install which
```

resolved the issue.

Really, the which command should be added to the list of utilities that mage:

vendor/magento/module-support/Helper/Shell.php